# Creating a heat map with ggplot

Tags: dictionary, ggplot2, heatmap

I am working with R and I would like to create a heat-map using Eurostat package and I am struggling with the palette. I know that there are several examples on the web but I was unable to fix this error.

I tried several kinds of palette, libraries, however, each of them threw some errors (the below refers to the Viridis library).

```
ERROR: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I would like to use a palette/library with blue colour (Dark blue - light blue/yellow). Would you be so kind as to help me?

PS. I am a newbie, all kinds of advice are welcome!

```
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)


data = get_eurostat("edat_lfse_03", time_format = "num")

data_map <- data%>%
  filter(age == 'Y25-34' & time == '2019' & isced11 == 'ED5-8' & geo != 'TR')%>%
  group_by(geo)%>%
  summarise(Values=mean(values, na.rm=TRUE))

mapdata <- get_eurostat_geospatial(nuts_level = 0, resolution='60',
                                   year=2016, 
                                   output_class = 'df') %>%
  right_join(data_map, by='geo')%>%
  mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(Values, n=7, decimals = 1))

map <- ggplot(mapdata, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) + 
  #scale_fill_manual("NOTHING WORKED HERE")+
  xlab('longitude')+  ylab('latitude') +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=mapdata$cat),color="white", size=.1)+ 
  xlim(c(-12,44)) + ylim(c(35,70)) + scale_fill_viridis_c()
map
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
xlim(c(-12,44)) + ylim(c(35,70)) + scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

use

```
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-12, 44)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(35, 70)) + scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

to convert the discrete value to the continuous one. This should work. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Yes! It works, thank you. Are you aware of a good quality palette like this Viridis one but with blue shades?